# Foxpro - Error 15: "Not A Table"

Tags: c#, .net, foxpro, dbase

I'm working on a C# application that reads/saves data in some old dbf-files.
(using Microsoft Visual FoxPro - driver)
I haven't had any problems until recently, when i tried querying a table i had'nt used before and i got this error message. This table is somewhat special since it has 500+ columns, i suspect that this might have something to do with it - but nothing I've googled so far gives any indications to this causing any problems.

I've had a look at [this document](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~NotATable) and checked that the header record count matches the actual count (1 record);
This document is the only good tip I've found so far, that does not require any heavy dbf-repair tools.

I've tried using both the Microsoft Visual FoxPro - and the VFPOLEDB driver, they both give more or less the same error message.

I've tried passing the `TableValidate = 0` command, without success.

Does anybody have any experience with a way to solve/work around this, preferably using C#.

Comment: what is the size of the dbf in which the table resides?

Comment: Thank you for your input - The size of the dbf is 25KB.

Comment: I read that one cause for the error could have been a dbf size of over 2GB, that's why I asked. Other sites say that the database is corrupted and using a program to fix the dbf would remove the error. You could make a backup of the database and try a fix program on it.

Comment: @Robban: as Tamar said, if the table has 500 columns it isn't a VFP table, maybe it can be a Clipper table.

Answer (score 4):

VFP tables don't support 500 columns, so this isn't a VFP table. You need to find out what kind of table it is and use the appropriate driver to open it.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is damaged, you can use [CmRepair.app](http://www.portalfox.com/index.php?name=Downloads&req=getit&lid=201) to fix it. This program is a Visual Foxpro 8 application (not a compiled .EXE), so you need VFP to execute it.

If you don't have VFP installed, you can download an [utility program](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25977913/runner.exe) I made to execute VFP scripts and .APPs in customers that haven't VFP installed. The VFP8 runtimes are available [here](http://www.foxpert.com/runtime.htm). Then you run the program with `runner CmRepair.app` and repair the table.

Good luck!

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment from Tamar, it got me to thinking of yet another application database that used .DBF file formats... Clipper.  Here's a link that describes their table capacities..

[Apollo database - (Clipper)](http://www.apollodb.com/apollo_engine.asp)

This might be a missing link you are looking for.